# Socket only recieves all Data, when client Thread sleeps?

Tags: java, sockets, streamwriter, thread-sleep, printwriter

i wanted to transfer bytes from my client to my server. So i created a PrintWriter to tell te Server, that new Data is coming and how long it will be. The Server now fetches the bytes send from a StreamWriter! It does work verry well as long as i set the Thread to Sleep 100 millis before sending the bytes. But i wonder why? The Client is an Android-Device! It also doesnt work with slow internet Connections... I hope someone can tell me my Error! Thanks a lot!

On the Client-Side (Sending):

```java
client = new Socket("SERVER_IP", 2411);
                    //client = new Socket ("chatblack.de",2411);
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
                    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                    streamer = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
```

```java
public void sendBytes(final byte[] toSend, int cID, int chunkID)
                      {
                          streamIsFree = false;
                         int length = toSend.length;
                         writer.println("DATA#"+cID+"#"+chunkID+"#"+length);
                         writer.flush();                     
//                               try 
//                           {
//                              Thread.sleep(1000);
//                          } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
//                              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//                              e1.printStackTrace();
//                          }

                        try 
                            {
                                streamer.write(toSend);
                                streamer.flush();
                            } 
                                 catch (IOException e) 
                                 {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                 }

                                 streamIsFree = true;
                                 System.out.println("Stream is free now!");
                    }
```

on the Server side:

```java
String nachricht;
boolean fileTransfer = false;

                    try {
                            while((nachricht = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                                {

                                  if(nachricht.startsWith("DATA"))
                                  {
                                      fileTransfer = true;
                                   //   writer.println("DATA#"+cID+"#"+chunkID+"#"+length);  sendet der Client!
                                    //  writer.println("DATA#"+cID+"#"+chunkID+"#"+length);
                                      String out =  uName+": DATA MESSAGE: "+nachricht;
                                      System.out.println(out);
                                      int cID = Integer.parseInt(nachricht.split("#")[1]);
                                      int chunkID = Integer.parseInt(nachricht.split("#")[2]);
                                      int length = Integer.parseInt(nachricht.split("#")[3]);
                                      byte[] buffer = new byte[length];

                                      System.out.println(uName+": recieving Data: "+buffer.length);
                                      byte[] data = getDataStream(length);
                                      ssc.bytesInput(cID, chunkID, data);
                                  }
//                                      if (nachricht.equals("DONE_DATA"))
//                                      {
//                                          fileTransfer = false;
//                                          System.out.println(uName+": SOCKET OPEN FOR STRINGS!");
//                                      }

                                  else if (!fileTransfer)
                                  {
                                      ssc.input(nachricht);
                                      String out =  uName+": Empfangenes Signal: "+nachricht;
                                      System.out.println(out);    
                                  }

                                  fileTransfer=false;

                                 }





                            System.out.println("Verbindungsabbruch durch verlassen des LOOPs: "+uName);
                            closeAllConnections();
                            startClientTimeOut();

                        }
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                            closeAllConnections();
                            startClientTimeOut();
                            System.out.println("Verbindung tot mit Client: "+uName);

                       // e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

            public byte[] getDataStream(int bytes)
            {
                try {
                    InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
                //    BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(in);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];


                    while(baos.size()<bytes)
                    {
                        int s;
                     if ((s=in.read(buffer))>0)
                     {
                     baos.write(buffer, 0, s);
                     if(baos.size()>=bytes)
                     {
                         break;
                     }
                     }

                     System.out.println(uName+": recieved bytes: "+baos.size());

                    }

                    byte result[] = baos.toByteArray(); 


                    return result;

                } 
                catch (IOException ex) 
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }

            }
```

The Server Console looks like this, when the Client Thread.sleep is disabled:

...
Sebi: recieved bytes: 71456
Sebi: recieved bytes: 72480
Sebi: recieved bytes: 73504
Sebi: recieved bytes: 74336
Sebi: recieved bytes: 75360
Sebi: recieved bytes: 75776
Sebi: recieved bytes: 76800
Sebi: recieved bytes: 77824
Sebi: recieved bytes: 78656
Sebi: recieved bytes: 79680
Sebi: recieved bytes: 80096
Sebi: recieved bytes: 81120
Sebi: recieved bytes: 81536
Sebi: recieved bytes: 82560
Sebi: recieved bytes: 83584
Sebi: recieved bytes: 84608
Sebi: recieved bytes: 85632
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86032
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86048
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86064
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86080
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86096
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86112
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86128
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86149
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86165
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86181
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86197
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86213
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86229
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86251
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86267
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86283
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86299
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86315
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86331
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86353
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86369
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86385
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86401
Sebi: recieved bytes: 86417

the bytes Array (the length) is exactly 102400! As I sad before... Everything works fine whith the sleep!

I hope someone can help me!
Thanks =)

Comment: Don't use two kinds of streams on the same socket. Both PrintWriter and PrintStream have buffers and if you use them both at the same time the data will get interleaved. It is also difficult to see how you can possibly read the data which is so produced.

Comment: But i firstly flush() the printWriter and then write to the PrintStream(i also tried with the normal outputStream) and flushing() the byteStream! 
And why does it work on wlan and a Thread.sleep()?

Comment: Is it possible, that the flush() method on the PrintWriter doesont wait till all data is flushed() and because of this the Stream gets interleaved?